# Why do I begin to feel good when hit hard?

Tags: elona-plus

Occasionally, while fighting, my character "begin[s] to feel good when hit hard." What does this mean? I've tried searching the [wikia](http://elona.wikia.com/wiki/Elona_Wiki) for the phrase, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: M-m-m-masochism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is flavor text that means that your [Constitution](http://elona.wikia.com/wiki/Constitution) score has gone up by one point. Usually because a number of things such as using [Constitution-based skills](http://elona.wikia.com/wiki/Skills#List_of_Skills) or eating certain kinds of [foods](http://elona.wikia.com/wiki/Food#Corpses). Of note, Medium Armor and Heavy Armor are CON skills that train simply by wearing that armor and moving around, while Polearms and Staves and Blunt all train just by attacking. But perhaps more to point - Healing, which is your natural recovery, trains any time you heal up. So Constitution tends to train pretty well in the background as a result, for any character.